# Please help me with jQuery.post. My script not giving an error nor posting form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I cant not figure out why this script doesn't work. It has to do with something within the AJAX POST script/function. Right now, when I hit submit on my form, it should pass the form values to ajax_profile.php page. It is not sending / posting form fields data. Please help me figure out the problem.
Here is my Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('Buddie_profile').submit(function () {

            $.post('ajax_profile.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {

                            if(data.success){ 

                                    $("body").showMessage({

                                        'thisMessage':  [data.message],

                                        'autoClose':    true,

                                        'className':    'tooltip',

                                        'delayTime':    8000,

                                        'displayNavigation':    false

                                    });

                                }else{

                                    $("body").showMessage({

                                        'thisMessage':  [data.message],

                                        'autoClose':    true,

                                        'className':    'tooltip',

                                        'delayTime':    8000,

                                        'displayNavigation':    false

                                    });

                                }

                            },'json');

                return false;
            });
});
```

here is my php file code for ajax_profile.php:

```
require('include/conn.php');


                                    $success= mysql_query("UPDATE birthbuddie SET 

                    Fname='".$_POST['FirstName']."',

                    Lname='".$_POST['SecondName']."',

                    Surname='".$_POST['Surname']."',

                    Dayofbirth='".$_POST['DayofBirth']."',

                    Monthofbirth ='".$_POST['MonthofBirth']."'

                    Yearofbirth='".$_POST['YearofBirth']."',

                    Ss='".$_POST['ss']."',

                    Mm='".$_POST['mm']."',

                    Hh='".$_POST['hh']."',

                    Countryofbirth='".$_POST['CountryofBirth']."',

                    Cityofbirth='".$_POST['CityofBirth']."',

                    Personalmsg='".$_POST['PersonalMessage']."',

                    WHERE BBId='".$_SESSION['userid']."'");


    if($success){

            $data['success']=true;
            $data['message']='You have updated changes successfully';

        }else{

            $data['success']=false;
            $data['message']='Update was not successful. Try again';
        }

        echo json_encode($data);
```

?>

Comment: what is your error, other than the [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)?

Comment: Displays no error, neither passes form values. Unable to figure out.

Comment: Please don't leave this question unanswered. I am very looking forward after posting my question on the stackoverflow.

Comment: Do you have a "demo", example page?

Comment: do you happen to know that there **IS** such a thing called `.serialize()` in jQuery that turns the form into a URI?

Answer (score 1):

You're not properly serializing the form data. You're not quoting the string values. You're not URI-encoding the form data. The way as you collected the form data may end up in a corrupt JSON object. This should have error'ed in the JavaScript console. You should have noticed this error if you paid attention to the JavaScript console in your browser (press F12 in Firebug/Chrome/IE9).

Assuming that `$('#Buddie_profile')` refers a HTML `<form id="Buddie_profile">`, then you should be [serializing](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) its data as follows:

```
$.post('ajax_profile.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
    // ...
});
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you've there some serious [SQL injection hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). If the enduser enters a valid partial SQL query string such as a (partial) `DROP` or `TRUNCATE` query in one of the input fields, then it'll get executed as well! Use [parameterized queries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) or at least [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: I have used .serialize() method. Still it is not sending values. Here is changed code:

Comment: I have edited the code above in javascript portion. It is still not sending values to the ajax_profile.php. I have this script within the same page inside body tag. First I want to solve the issue in Ajax passing, then I will surely write a perfect script in sql injection.

Comment: Then the URL is likely just wrong. To be sure, track in the browser's web developer toolset (press F12 in Firebug/Chrome/IE9)

Comment: Even I tried this    $('form').submit(function() {
  alert($(this).serialize());
  return false;
}); It doesn't show alert box.

Comment: Apparently the selector is wrong. Note that you've removed `#` from your `$('Buddie_profile')` selector. Why? There is no such HTML element as `<Buddie_profile>` in the document, right? If you want to select `<form id="Buddie_profile">` then you need `$('#Buddie_profile')` (and you should have only one of it throughout your document).

Comment: It is working now. But giving error of fail. I am trying to figure it out where is the problem actually. I have updated ajax_profile.php code. Please check and suggest.

Comment: You forgot to mention details about the error. In any way, your initial question is likely solved. It's posting to PHP now. Feel free to ask a new question wherein you just concentrate on the PHP part.

Comment: I made it working with the help of you all. Thanks a lot. there was a mistake in my SQL. thank you all once again.